# How to collect data from CRM Dynamics using Nifi?

Tags: api, bigdata, dynamics-crm, apache-nifi

how can i collect data from CRM Dynamics using nifi
Get CRM DATA using REST API (NIFI)
please help!

I searched for videos and tutorials but couldn't find one thing that can help me

Comment: There is no native support to connect Dynamics CRM from NiFi (processor or controller service). You can download the JDBC jar for Dynamics CRM and configure `DBCPConnectionPool` controller service to connect with it.

Comment: i try to do it with invokehttp but i still can't retreive the data from the crm dynamics is there any solution or a tutorial that can help thanks

Comment: If you are trying with InvokeHTTP then this might be helpful - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg334279(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN